# Jenkins parameter passed to Maven plugin by default - how to ignore this?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I am using maven plugin in my build job and the properties required are added in Properties text box like below

**exec.classpathScope=test**

My build consists of few parameters [eg: msg="hi"]
When maven build happens, along with the property specified, jenkins job parameters are also passed like below

**mvn -Dmsg=hi -Dexec.classpathScope=test clean**

I want to ignore passing job parameters to maven plugin.
How to do that?

Comment: Remove the parameters from the Job definition in Jenkins...

Comment: Those parameters are required which will be used in other shell commands. Hence it can't be removed

Comment: Than you are doing something wrong. Those parameters are recoginized from plugins and that means you configuration in Jenkins is wrong...Given parameters can't ignored...

Comment: Parameters given in Jenkins is for totally different purpose and has no link with the maven build. In order to avoid parameters passing to Maven plugin, **removing parameters** is not a right solution. Job configurations are correct.

Comment: The exec.classpath parameter is for exec-maven-plugin So now?

Comment: "msg" is a jenkins string parameter and that is also passed along with exec.classpathScope. I want some option that specifies to ignore jenkins job parameters being passed to mvn plugin. I want my mvn command to be **mvn -Dexec.classpathScope=test clean** instead of **mvn -Dmsg=hi -Dexec.classpathScope=test clean**

Comment: Do you mean you want to call Maven via `mvn -Dexec.classpathScope=test clean` instead of `mvn -Dmsg=Hi -Dexec.classpathScope=test clean`? If so you need to handle that via a shell call in Jenkins and check if the parameter is set or just ignore it...but maven plugins do not have an option to ignore parameters cause it does not make sense.